# PHP remote file download with custom name set

Tags: php, file, file-upload, upload

I have this script here, which gets me remote file to my server

The problem is, if I want to rename the file, I have to manually ftp to the server and rename the file. Is there anyway to name the file before downloading?

```
<?php

if($_POST){
//get the url
$url = $_POST['url'];

//add time to the current filename
$name = basename($url);
list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $name);
$name = $txt.time();
$name = $name.".".$ext;

//here is the actual code to get the file from the url and save it to the uploads folder
//get the file from the url using file_get_contents and put it into the folder using file_put_contents
$upload = file_put_contents("uploads/$name",file_get_contents($url));
//check success
if($upload)  echo "Success: <a href='uploads/".$name."' target='_blank'>Check Uploaded</a>"; else "please check your folder permission";
}
?>

<html>
<head><title>File Upload from URL</title></head>
<body>
<h3>File Upload from URL</h3>
    <form action="" method="post">
        Your URL: <input type="text" name="url" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone help, I will be so happy.

I have to manually rename the file,that's the problem,In anyway or another can i specify a name before i upload?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The path to the new file is the first parameter for `file_put_contents` just pass there `"uploads/{$new_name}"`

where `$new_name= "desired_file_name.". $ext";`

Comment: Still i have to edit the php file,I meant a input box where i can specify the name

Comment: You can do something similar with Javascript's `FileAPI` - but it is a bit of an overkill and won't be browser compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Use php rename method...
[Check](http://pk1.php.net/rename)

```
<?php
    rename("file.txt", "new_file.txt");
?>
```